# Use one QPushButton with two QLineEdits, depending on last focus

Tags: python, pyside, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I have a window, which has two QLineEdits in it. They are Line 1 and Line 2. I have a Backspace QPushButton which is to be pressed. I want some code which, when the backspace is pressed, will delete the text from the desired QLineEdit. This is to be done based on which one is focused at the time.

I understand that currently my code will backspace line1, however I want it to delete whichever line edit most recently had focus (i.e. if line1 was selected before backspace, it will get backspaced, if line 2 was the last in focus, then it will be backspaced).

I'm thinking it requires an if statement or 2, not sure though. How do I choose which line edit is deleted based on which one last had focus?

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtCore import*
from PySide.QtGui import*

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):                                                                                    #The Main Window Class Maker

    def __init__(self,):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(('cleanlooks'))

        mfont = QFont()
        mfont.setFamily("BankGothic LT")
        mfont.setPointSize(40)
        mfont.setBold(True)
        xfont = QFont()
        xfont.setFamily("BankGothic LT")
        xfont.setPointSize(40)
        xfont.setLetterSpacing(QFont.AbsoluteSpacing, 15)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit("Line 1", self)
        self.line1.setFixedSize(460, 65)
        self.line1.setFont(xfont)
        self.line1.move(10,10)

        self.line2 = QLineEdit("Line 2", self)
        self.line2.setFixedSize(460, 65)
        self.line2.setFont(xfont)
        self.line2.move(10,200)


        #BackSpace button
        back = QPushButton("BackSpace", self)
        back.move(100,100)
        back.setFixedSize(300,75)
        back.setFont(mfont)
        back.clicked.connect(self.line1.backspace)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("BackSpace")
    window.resize(480, 400)
    window.setMaximumSize(480,400)
    window.setMinimumSize(480,400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, so I kept working on this in order to find a useful situation, where one would use this sort of functionality.
Say you were trying to create a login form for a touch screen, but you had no onscreen keyboard installed, you can 'create' one. This is what the intended use was for.

I've sort of tested this, and fixed any bugs I saw, but hey, feel free to use it. I noticed that heaps of examples existed for calculators, but no real examples existed for Keypad or Numberpad entry. Enjoy!

```
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
    from PySide.QtCore import*
    from PySide.QtGui import*

    class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):                                                                                    #The Main Window Class Maker

    def __init__(self,):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(('cleanlooks'))

        U = QLabel("U:", self)
        U.move(10,10)
        P = QLabel("P:", self)
        P.move(10,50)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit("", self)
        self.line1.move(20,10)
        self.line1.setReadOnly(True)

        self.line2 = QLineEdit("", self)
        self.line2.move(20,50)
        self.line2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line2.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        #PushButtons
        back = QPushButton("<", self)
        back.move(100,80)
        back.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        back.setFixedSize(20,20)
        one = QPushButton('1', self)
        one.move(10,80)
        one.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        one.setText("1")
        one.setFixedSize(20,20)
        two = QPushButton('2', self)
        two.move(40,80)
        two.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        two.setFixedSize(20,20)
        three = QPushButton('3', self)
        three.move(70,80)
        three.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        three.setFixedSize(20,20)
        four = QPushButton('4', self)
        four.move(10,110)
        four.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        four.setFixedSize(20,20)
        five = QPushButton('5', self)
        five.move(40,110)
        five.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        five.setFixedSize(20,20)
        six = QPushButton('6', self)
        six.move(70,110)
        six.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        six.setFixedSize(20,20)
        seven = QPushButton('7', self)
        seven.move(10,140)
        seven.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        seven.setFixedSize(20,20)
        eight = QPushButton('8', self)
        eight.move(40,140)
        eight.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        eight.setFixedSize(20,20)
        nine = QPushButton('9', self)
        nine.move(70,140)
        nine.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        nine.setFixedSize(20,20)
        zero = QPushButton('0', self)
        zero.move(100,140)
        zero.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        zero.setFixedSize(20,20)
        enter = QPushButton("E", self)
        enter.move(100,110)
        enter.setFixedSize(20,20)
        enter.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)


                #click Handles
        def handleBackspace():
            backh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if backh is self.line1 or backh is self.line2:
                backh.backspace()
        def handleZero():
            zeroh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if zeroh is self.line1:
                zeroh.setText((self.line1.text()+str('0')))
            else:
                zeroh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('0'))
        def handleOne():
            oneh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if oneh is self.line1:
                oneh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('1'))
            else:
                oneh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('1'))
        def handleTwo():
            twoh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if twoh is self.line1:
                twoh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('2'))
            else:
                twoh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('2'))
        def handleThree():
            threeh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if threeh is self.line1:
                threeh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('3'))
            else:
                threeh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('3'))
        def handleFour():
            fourh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if fourh is self.line1:
                fourh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('4'))
            else:
                 fourh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('4'))
        def handleFive():
            fiveh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if fiveh is self.line1:
                fiveh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('5'))
            else:
                fiveh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('5'))
        def handleSix():
            sixh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if sixh is self.line1:
                sixh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('6'))
            else:
                sixh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('6'))
        def handleSeven():
            sevenh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if sevenh is self.line1:
                sevenh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('7'))
            else:
                sevenh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('7'))
        def handleEight():
            eighth = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if eighth is self.line1:
                eighth.setText(self.line1.text()+str('8'))
            else:
                eighth.setText(self.line2.text()+str('8'))
        def handleNine():
            nineh = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
            if nineh is self.line1:
                nineh.setText(self.line1.text()+str('9'))
            else:
                nineh.setText(self.line2.text()+str('9'))

        #Click Conditions
        self.connect(enter, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.close)
        zero.clicked.connect(handleZero)
        nine.clicked.connect(handleNine)
        eight.clicked.connect(handleEight)
        seven.clicked.connect(handleSeven)
        six.clicked.connect(handleSix)
        five.clicked.connect(handleFive)
        four.clicked.connect(handleFour)
        three.clicked.connect(handleThree)
        two.clicked.connect(handleTwo)
        one.clicked.connect(handleOne)
        back.clicked.connect(handleBackspace)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("LoginWindow")
    window.resize(130, 180)
    window.setMaximumSize(130, 180)
    window.setMinimumSize(130, 180)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by utilizing the [`editingFinished`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal and some manipulation of which line edit is connected to your `backspace` function.

I'll post then entire code block and then explain the changes I made below it.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self,):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(('cleanlooks'))

        mfont = QFont()
        mfont.setFamily("BankGothic LT")
        mfont.setPointSize(40)
        mfont.setBold(True)
        xfont = QFont()
        xfont.setFamily("BankGothic LT")
        xfont.setPointSize(40)
        xfont.setLetterSpacing(QFont.AbsoluteSpacing, 15)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit("Line 1", self)
        self.line1.setFixedSize(460, 65)
        self.line1.setFont(xfont)
        self.line1.move(10,10)

        self.line2 = QLineEdit("Line 2", self)
        self.line2.setFixedSize(460, 65)
        self.line2.setFont(xfont)
        self.line2.move(10,200)

        self.recent_line = self.line2
        self.previous_line = self.line1

        #BackSpace button
        self.back = QPushButton("BackSpace", self)
        self.back.move(100,100)
        self.back.setFixedSize(300,75)
        self.back.setFont(mfont)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.recent_line.backspace)

        self.line1.editingFinished.connect(self.last_lineedit)
        self.line2.editingFinished.connect(self.last_lineedit)

    def last_lineedit(self):
        if isinstance(self.sender(), QLineEdit):
            self.recent_line, self.previous_line = self.previous_line, self.recent_line
            self.back.clicked.disconnect(self.previous_line.backspace)
            self.back.clicked.connect(self.recent_line.backspace)
```

---

The first change that I've made is to include two new variables so that we can keep track of which `QLineEdit` was focused on last:

```
self.recent_line = self.line2
self.previous_line = self.line1
```

Next, I changed your `back` widget to be `self.back`, because we are going to need it outside of `__init__`

```
self.back = QPushButton("BackSpace", self)
self.back.move(100,100)
self.back.setFixedSize(300,75)
self.back.setFont(mfont)
self.back.clicked.connect(self.recent_line.backspace)
```

Then we are going to set up both `line1` and `line2` to the `editingFinished` signal.

> This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus.

We'll be utilizing the "loses focus" part, because when the `self.back` button is pressed, the QLineEdit has lost focus.

Finally we get to the function that is going to keep track of which `QLineEdit` is connected to the backspace button at any given time.

```
def last_lineedit(self):
    if isinstance(self.sender(), QLineEdit):
        self.recent_line, self.previous_line = self.previous_line, self.recent_line
        self.back.clicked.disconnect(self.previous_line.backspace)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.recent_line.backspace)
```

Within this function, we fist ensure that only one of the QLineEdits are sending the signal (just in case you connect something else to this signal that isn't a QLineEdit).

Next, we swap which `QLineEdit` was most recently focused on:

```
self.recent_line, self.previous_line = self.previous_line, self.recent_line
```

Then we disconnect from the previous line and connect to the new line. These last two lines are the magic that allows you to delete from both lines based on which had focus most recently. These lines are also why we changed to `self.back`, instead of leaving it at `back`. The locally scoped `back` wasn't accessible from the `last_lineedit` function.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if the backspace button didn't steal focus. That way, the caret will stay visible in the line-edit that has focus, and the user can easily see exactly what is happening. Doing it this way also makes the code much simpler:

```
        back.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        back.clicked.connect(self.handleBackspace)

    def handleBackspace(self):
        widget = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
        if widget is self.line1 or widget is self.line2:
            widget.backspace()
```